# Scrape table method by vba

Tags: vba, excel

I tried that code, and it doesn't work properly.
It should get the table (number 20 - Order Book (XBT/EUR) by selling, right one). However I am getting an error :

> Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)

What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub Kraken()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim tbls, tbl, trs, tr, tds, td, r, c

    Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    IE.navigate "https://www.kraken.com/charts"
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)

    Set tbl = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")(17)
    Set trs = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")

    For r = 0 To trs.Length - 1
        Set tds = trs(r).getElementsByTagName("td")
        If tds.Length = 0 Then Set tds = trs(r).getElementsByTagName("th")

        For c = 0 To tds.Length - 1
            ActiveSheet.Range("B20").Offset(r, c).Value = tds(c).innerText
        Next c
    Next r
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Use table  `1` as `Set tbl = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")(1)`

Comment: oh wow, so i just have to type from 1-2 and find the table? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah that's working thank you!

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer, kindly mark it as accepted to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because `IE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")(17)` gives nothing to `tbl`.

For `Order Book (XBT/EUR)` use table `1` as:

```
Set tbl = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")(1)
```